# Clarification about keras.utils.Sequence

Tags: python, multithreading, keras, deep-learning, multiprocessing

Keras have very little info about [keras.utils.Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/), actually the only reason I want to derive my batch generator from `keras.utils.Sequence` is that I want to not to write thread pool with queue by myself, but I'm not sure if it's best choice for my task, here is my questions:

1. What should `__len__` return if I have random generator and I don't
   have any predefined 'list' with samples.
2. How `keras.utils.Sequence`
       should be used with `fit_generator`, I'm interested in
       `max_queue_size`,`workers`, `use_multiprocessing`, `shuffle`
       parameters mostly.
3. What are other options avalible in keras?

Answer (score 14):

1. Anything you want, considering that one epoch will get `len` batches from the Sequence.
2. There is no secret, use it as any other generator, with the difference that you may do `steps_per_epoch=len(generator)` or `steps_per_epoch=None`.

   - `max_queue_size`: any value, this will load batches that will be waiting in memory until their turn to get into the model
   - `workers`: any value, this will be the number of parallel "threads" (forgive me if the name is not precise) that will be loading batches
   - `use_multiprocessing`: I don't know this one. It was not necessary for me and the only time I tried it was buggy enough to freeze my machine
   - `shuffle`: From [the documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator): Boolean. Whether to shuffle the **order of the batches** at the beginning of each epoch. Only used with instances of Sequence (keras.utils.Sequence). Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not None.
3. I think this is it. If you want to thread the model itself, then you might want to read about multi GPU training, I guess.

**Advantages of `Sequence` over a regular generator:**

With sequence, it's possible to keep track of which batches were already taken, which batches are sent to which thread for loading, and there will never be a conflict because it's based on indices.

With generator, parallel processing will lose track of what batches were already taken or not because threads don't talk to each other and there is no other option than yielding batch by batch sequentially.

**Advantages of generators and sequences over a loop**

In a loop, you will "wait for batch load", "wait for model training", "wait for batch load", "wait for model training".

With `fit_generator`, batches will be loaded "while" the model is training, you have both things happening simultaneously.

For very simple generators, there won't be a big impact. For complex generators, augmentators, big image loaders, etc., the generation time is very significant and may severely impact your speed.

Comment: About `1.` : i.e. if I have random generator inside `keras.utils.Sequence` I can return any number from `__len__` like 100000 as far as I set `steps_per_epoch` to correct value?

Comment: About `2.` : as I understand `shuffle` is useless in case of random generator, but suppose I have some fixed list of samples inside `keras.utils.Sequence` should I implement some mechanism of random list permutation in class derived from `keras.utils.Sequence` or it will be shuffled anyway somewhere in the other code?

Comment: About `3.` : I mean what purpose of `keras.utils.Sequence`? why I should prefer it to simple batch generator implemented by hand that `yeld` batches in `while` loop? Is there any other class like `keras.utils.Sequence` from which I can derive?

Comment: See updated answer. I think there is no other class.

Comment: 1 - Yes. /// 2 - Keras will shuffle "the batch indices", which batch comes first. If you want to shuffle your list before yielding batches, you can do a shuffle in a `on_epoch_end` method inside the sequence.

Comment: Is `keras.utils.Sequence` appropriate to use for multiple files? If so, how would `__len__` and `__getitem__` be handled? Are there any best practices for multiple files? Particularly multiple tfrecords files?

Comment: You create your `Sequence` the way you want doing what you want. You handle the `__len__` and `__getitem__` the way you want. The code is totally free. You just need to return `x` and `y`.