# ImageDataGenerator - Preprocessing X_train

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, generator

I have two datasets. The first one contains the image data paths, so the path to my inputs `X_train`. The second dataset contains the labels, they are one hot encoded and in a special format, their shape is 3-dimensional (number of images, length of the label, character possibilities), i.e. `(n, 8, 36)` for my dataset. The labels are the `y_train` data.

The shape of the labels is the reason why I am looking for why I am looking for a method to read in and preprocess `X_train` batchwise and separately from the `y_train` data. Is there such a method or do you know how to work around this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can create a custom generator with keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom keras generator by creating a class which inherits from [Sequence class](https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#sequence-class)

Another [SO answer with more details[([Clarification about keras.utils.Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620163/clarification-about-keras-utils-sequence))

Here's an example

```
class Custom_Generator(keras.utils.Sequence) :
    def __init__(self,...,datapath, batch_size, ..) :

    def __len__(self) :
        #calculate data len, something like len(train_labels)


    def load_and_preprocess_function(self, label_names, ...):
        #do something...
        #load data for the batch using label names with whatever library

    def __getitem__(self, idx) :
        batch_y = train_labels[idx:idx+batch_size]
        batch_x = self.load_and_preprocess_function()
        return ( batch_x, batch_y )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I maybe come back to you in chat or via mail in case of problems? That would be super nice :-)

Comment: If you have other problems, you hopefully will be able to find on stack overflow, or raise a new question so it can help someone in the future